# How to Chain multiple methods where each methods main thread has passed while inner thread is still working?

Tags: java, multithreading, rest

I have code like this. Each method is a stage exposed to rest call independently:

```
void methodA(@FormDataParam ("fd") fd){
//Executor spawns thread - takes around 15-30 min as per data
//main thread exits with "Process begun" message while thread spawned still running
}

void methodB(){
//Executor spawns thread - takes around 60-600 min as per data
//main thread exits with "Process begun" message while thread spawned still running
}

void methodC(){
//Executor spawns thread - takes around 10-60 min as per data
//main thread exits with "Process begun" message while thread spawned still running
}
```

These stages were executed sequentially earlier. Now, additional requirement is  to execute them in one go if required. For that one single api has to be exposed as rest api like:

```
void methodAll(@FormDataParam ("fd") fd){
methodA(fd);
methodB();
methodC();
}
```

Problem is methodA(), methodB(), methodC() main thread return immediately while threads spawned by them are still running and hence result in start of execution of other subsequent methods before prior one completes.

I am in fix, how to solve this problem without substantial changes to existing three api?

Comment: One way -- use and pass in call backs

Comment: MetgodB needs result of methodA for make it's job?

Comment: Best would be to refactor the code such that the three methods don't return void and don't do threading. Instead they simply perform their actions and return their results, then call the three in succession within a single background thread.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for looking into it. Yes, refactoring is one way as you suggested but I am keeping it as last option as it hinders with current execution pattern of independent run. If  I dont get any better solution then I will go with it.

Comment: @djxak - no friend. MethodB doesnt need input from MethodA but since these are lifecycle stages methodA must complete before methodB. Actually, currently methodA writes its status in a DB table. methodB never starts if doesnt have status completed corresponding to methodA. Hence one way is to loop around with sleep of certain time over status but I am open to other better solutions.

Comment: @KRS then do what @HovercraftFullOfEels suggested. But I don't see how this refactoring can hinder current execution pattern of independent run. You just add 1 more layer between actual job method and REST controller: creating new thread. Your REST controller's methods (A, B and C) will create new thread and run your service's methods A, B and C (which not create any threads themselves) in this thread. Your new `methodAll` method of REST controller will do just the same: run all three service's methods sequentially in new thread.

Comment: @djxak - HovercraftFullOfEels suggests not to use thread & respond as method completes (in 1 case it wld be >5 hrs). This requires talking to all Users of restApi & inform abt impact (eg. any timeout shld stop ). Here, I dont add any layer. Jst remove threading part.
FYI - Methods do validation, preprocess & postProcess before/after  spawning thread which calls service method. Exception handling in main & spawned thread is there. Separating only service method wld lead to  writing complete similar code in methodAll as well, which will lead to duplicate code & maintenance problem going ahead.

Comment: @KRS, no, you misunderstood his answer. It recommens to move your methods from your rest controller and then these methods will *not* do any threading. REST controllers will do. Then you can compose this new methods (which not threading) in new controller method.

Comment: I added this idea as answer because it is too many to describe in comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you have (pseudocode):

```
class RestController {

  void methodA() {
    new Thread() {
      // some hard work
    }.start();
  }

  void methodB() {
    new Thread() {
      // some hard work
    }.start();
  }

}
```

After refactoring:

```
class RestController {

  void methodA() {
    new Thread() {
      service.methodA();
    }.start();
  }

  void methodB() {
    new Thread() {
      service.methodB();
    }.start();
  }

  void methodD() {
    new Thread() {
      service.methodA();
      service.methodB();
    }.start();
  }

}

class Service {

  void methodA() {
    // some hard work
  }

  void methodB() {
    // some hard work
  }

}
```

Of course you can use [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) or any other helpers for threading instead of manual thread spawning.

If your controller do validation, preprocess & postProcess before/after spawning thread, as you say, and it really the same code, then you can extract it into method which takes `Runnable` and executes it between pre- and postProcess to avoid duplication.

```
  void execute(Runnable runnable) {
    // do validation
    // do preProcess
    new Thread(runnable).start();
    // do postProcess
  }
...
  void methodA() {
    execute(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      void run() {
        service.methodA();
      }
    });
  }
```

Or you can just do this validation in your service methods.

Comment: Here is the problem. If I call service.methodA(); from RestController new method executeALL then I will miss validation, and processing. And if I call execute method in RestCOntroller then I dont know whether threads spawned have completed.

Comment: I used idea from your code above to implement mine.  we are thinking of restructuring complete code to using CompletableFuture.

Comment: We are thinking of restructuring complete code to using CompletableFuture. But, I took a leaf out of your suggestion & what worked is: Copy complete code of existing api in another method having additional boolean input like 'toChain'. While calling from executeall tochain will be true & from individual apis it eill be false. put following at last of new method (obviously after executor shutdown) -  If toChain is true then use executor.awaittermination (Timeperiod given to await is sufficientlyhigh from what is takes) to await on all threads to complete & executor of individual api complete.